# Best way to cron jobs on Windows

Tags: windows, cron, scheduler, jobs

I need a **Job Scheduler** / **Cron Jobs** on **Windows 7**.

I need through command line  set a **start date** (with day, month and year), a **start time** (with hour, minute and second), a **job name** and a **command**.

I tried with **schtasks**, but the seconds doesn't work (starts at 10:20:00):

```
schtasks /Create /SC ONCE /ST 10:20:30 /TN MyApp /TR calc.exe
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, schtasks does not support seconds.

Comment: I thought schtasks supports seconds: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814596/en-us?fr=1, but testing it, I realized that not working, Is there an alternative?

Comment: Not sure, to be honest. This post seems to indicate that there's nothing free... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769635/windows-task-scheduler-to-execute-tasks-in-seconds