# Keep two files in different folders in sync on Windows

Tags: windows, synchronization

Let's say I have

```
c:\prod\foo.txt
```

and

```
c:\work\foo.txt
```

I would like to get c:\prod\foo.txt automatically and immediately updated from the other file, whenever I change & save c:\work\foo.txt

How can this be accomplished? Installing tools is okay. Windows 7 and up.
Symbolic linking is not a solution for me, as the c:\work is deleted every now and then.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [SyncToy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SyncToy)?

[A: Run SyncToy silently](https://superuser.com/questions/174345/run-synctoy-silently/174375?s=20%7C0.8650#174375)  addresses this issue.

SyncToy can be used in conjunction with the Windows Scheduler to automate sync operations.

Comment: what is the smallest interval on Windows Scheduler? A minute? 1 minute is too long, a few seconds would be okay.

Comment: Please modify your question to specify all your requirements otherwise people cannot provide meaningful solutions.

Comment: Andre's answer explains how to do it in increments of less than a minute:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769635/windows-task-scheduler-to-execute-tasks-in-seconds

Comment: 60 triggers is kinda awkward solution...
I'm probably looking for a tool watching on a file in a loop and coping it on a change...