# How to check schedule task every three second and print second in label using c#

Tags: c#, wpf, scheduled-tasks, taskservice

I want to run my schedule task after 3 second, for that i have written code in my WPF application.

```
 using (var ts = new TaskService())
 { 
     TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
     td.Settings.MultipleInstances = TaskInstancesPolicy.IgnoreNew;
     td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "TestAPP";

     var trigger = new TimeTrigger();
     trigger.Repetition.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3000);
     lblProcess.Content = DateTime.Now.Second; //print current second in a label. 
     td.Triggers.Add(trigger);

     td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, null, System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)));

     ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(@"TestTask", td);
 }
```

Here i want to check that after ruining from VS, it will run every 3 second or not, so I've print current second to the label `lblProcess`.

But it does not updated on every 3 second, Am I doing anything wrong?

**EDIT-1:**

I've read this before : [Creating Scheduled Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394806/creating-scheduled-tasks)

There is nothing like to how to check.

**Edit-2:**

If i use `3.0` instead of `3000` then it's give me an error.

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.Parameter
>   name: Interval

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating Scheduled Tasks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394806/creating-scheduled-tasks)

Comment: @TeunvanderWijst have your read my whole question or just find it in google and mark as duplicate , just read it first

Comment: if you want to trigger every 3 seconds, just try Timer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410430/wpf-timer-like-c-sharp-timer

Comment: @zquanghoangz, I want to do that with Task Scheduler only!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set interval in Task Scheduler less than one minute

Comment: OK, Can you please give me some reference, where it stated

Comment: You can look here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a0a06158-4c94-4f2a-ac32-3e1e555fd54d/how-to-run-task-every-30-seconds?forum=w7itprogeneral And here is the solution to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769635/windows-task-scheduler-to-execute-tasks-in-seconds (scheduling 59 triggers)

Answer (score 1):

```
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
```

When passing 3000 you input 3000 seconds.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromseconds(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I just hit `F12` and method having summery like this *// Parameters://   value://     A number of seconds, accurate to the nearest millisecond.*

Comment: And read from link which you posted : `A number of seconds, accurate to the nearest millisecond`

Comment: True. It is accurate to the nearest millisecond but to input milliseconds you use a double data type not int. So it takes 3000 as 3000 seconds not 3.000 seconds

Comment: If use like you suggested it's give me an error of **Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.Parameter name: Interval**

Comment: **You cannot set interval in Task Scheduler less than one minute**, it's not *TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);.* Issue